# Another Instance of Main activity created on top of deep link when user clicks on the notification in locked state (android)

Tags: android, deep-linking

I am working on an android application. I am using deep links for push notifications. When the phone is in unlocked state and the notification comes, the deep links works fine and the user goes to the page provided in the deep link, **but when the device is in locked state and user double clicks on notification to unlock the device and open the app, the deep link still works but another instance of main activity gets created on top of the deep link page**. Can some one please provide me the solution to this problem ?

Comment: Did you try to set the launchMode attribute of this activity, or change the Intent flags?

Comment: Please post your full code@Ankit

Comment: PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivities(context, 0, new Intent[]{backIntent, mainIntent},
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
And back Intent has flags - FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP